# ISS 7 - how to know when user have shut down an app?

Tags: iis, iis-7

Is there a log file, which contains the user actions made inside IIS 7, like shutting down an app, cleaning the app pool, restart the server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to enable IIS Configuration Auditing.

1) Navigate to the target server where Internet Information Services (IIS) is installed.

2) Start Event Viewer (Click Start / Run type eventvwr.msc and press Enter)

3) Navigate to the following node: Event Viewer / Applications and Services Logs / Microsoft / Windows / IIS-Configuration

4) Right click on the Operational log and select Properties.

5) Turn on the Enable logging checkbox, specify the Maximum log size option as 299968 Kb, select Overwrite events as needed option and click OK.

Personally I'd also use [Netwrix Auditor](http://www.netwrix.com/tracking/track.html?cID=70170000000kgFr&url=https://www.netwrix.com/windows_server_audit.html) to make information readable and not go crazy reading all those events.
Additional info here https://www.netwrix.com/kb/1720